# Display input text value that is stored on a variable

Tags: php

Is there something wrong in this simple code? I'm trying to store input type weight into a php variable $w....tried echo $w to check if it has been stored but it doesn't display anything..:p

```
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<form action='' method='POST'>
    <label>Enter Weight: </label><input type='text' name="weight">
</form>
<?php 
   $w=$_POST["weight"]; 
   echo $w; 
?>
```

Comment: use `isset()` or `!empty()`. [you should be getting an undefined index notice.](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php)

Comment: `if (isset($_POST["weight"])) 
  {
  $w=$_POST["weight"]; 
  echo $w;
  }` Always check and assign !

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-and-notice-undefined-index

Comment: ahm thanks but it still won't display th value of $w

Comment: @arkaem What is the error you getting ?

Comment: no error..it just wont display $w...$w is the php variable that supposed to have the value of the inputted weight...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should work as expected

What you have to do is to assign after checking is done

```
if (isset($_POST['weight']))
{ 
   $w=$_POST["weight"]; 
   echo $w; 
}
```

So your code should be

```
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<form action='' method='POST'>
<label>Enter Weight: </label><input type='text' name="weight">
<input type="submit">
</form>
<?php 
if (isset($_POST['weight']))
{

   $w=$_POST["weight"]; 
   echo $w; 
}
?>
```

And it should display your input after the submit button is pressed.

Comment: Oh my,,,completely forgot the submit thing...thanks...lol..:)

Comment: @arkaem That's ok, Everyone has a learning point :)

Comment: i assumed that it would work...but still no display...hmm weird

Comment: @arkaem Can't get you.. It is not outputing the input ?

Comment: oh now it does..my bad...thanks sir!!!... I was dragging my project folder directly to my browser..when I should've run it from Localhost...:D thanks a lot

Comment: ha ha, Yes it should be :) Welcome :)